# How do you use a VHD?

Tags: vhd

How do I use a Microsoft VHD file?  How do I run it?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738372.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's a virtual-pc hard drive file. Install virtual pc and select the VHD to run. I assume you're trying to use XP-mode.

Comment: I have Windows 7.  When I install Virtual PC and run it, all it does is open a directory InternetUser\Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [**V** irtual **H** ard **D** isk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format)), to be used with [VirtualPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) or another similar program that supports the VHD format - like [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualbox).

Comment: VirtualPC does not work at all -- all it does is open a directory.  I'll try VirtualPC.

Comment: I'll try VirtualBox, I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps listed here: http://www.kodyaz.com/tools/how-to-mount-vhd-file-virtual-disk-without-virtual-pc-vpc.aspx to do this without using a Virtual PC. You can use a free program called  Gizmo Central

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't need additional software to mount VHD files as another HDD. In Disk Managed (available from Computer Management) use Action | Attach VHD.